# How can I create an auto respond to emails with specific files depending on the form filled in on my site?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I create an auto respond to emails with specific files depending on the form filled in on my site?

My client wants a form on their website in which customers will select specific details about the product. If it’s a clothing product, they’ll select the following options (for example):

Type: T-shirt
Color: Green
Print: Cat

Now the customer needs to receive a reply with a file (pre-photographed) of what they want.

It's a Wordpress site, and Contact Form 7 is being used for mails.

Comment: do you have any code that you have tried with?

Comment: I have not.. I've not tried anything so far

Answer (score 0):

You must do a router who it will route according form filled.

For exemple your router when it get a post /form/tshirt3 it will send a mail with the correspond text.